# How to add and remove class with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-class

I have a few buttons that work like switchers. If you click one it becomes active and "shuts down" other buttons. I did this using jQuery but would like to use AngularJS. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-energized" id="weak">weak</a>
    <a class="button button-energized" id="normal">normal</a>
    <a class="button button-energized" id="strong">strong</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

        $('#weak').click(function() {
            $('#weak').addClass('active');
            $('#normal').removeClass('active');
            $('#strong').removeClass('active');
        });

        $('#normal').click(function() {
            $('#normal').addClass('active');
            $('#weak').removeClass('active');
            $('#strong').removeClass('active');
        });

        $('#strong').click(function() {
            $('#strong').addClass('active');
            $('#normal').removeClass('active');
            $('#weak').removeClass('active');
        });

   });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could have `ng-click` that can toggle `selected` flag, that could be use with `ng-class` to bind / unbind class.

**Markup**

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-energized" id="weak" 
       ng-class="{active: $parent.selected=='weak'}" ng-click="$parent.selected='weak'">
      weak
    </a>
    <a class="button button-energized" id="normal" 
       ng-class="{active: selected=='normal'}" ng-click="selected='normal'">
        normal
    </a>
    <a class="button button-energized" id="strong" 
       ng-class="{active: selected=='strong'}" ng-click="selected='strong'">
        strong
    </a>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/2221/)

**Better way**

You could easily do this by using `ng-repeat` which will reduce your line of code.

**Markup**

```
$scope.strengths = ["weak","normal","strong"];
```

**Code**

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-energized" id="{{strength}}" 
       ng-class="{active: $parent.selected == strength}" 
       ng-click="$parent.selected=strength"
       ng-repeat="strength in strengths">
      {{strength}}
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @soosmca Thanks mate for the fiddle

Comment: The first example is cool, how can I make it work with the first option with "active" class by default?

Comment: @SoulEeater what do you mean by active class by default?

Comment: @PankajParkar what I mean is that if I want the first option (in the fiddle example: "weak") to be colored red at the moment you open the page: The first option already selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> angular.element(document.querySelector("#cntrlID")).removeClass("customclass");

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-energized" id="weak" ng-click=removeNS()>weak</a>
    <a class="button button-energized" id="normal" ng-click=removeWS()>normal</a>
    <a class="button button-energized" id="strong" ng-click=removeWN()>strong</a>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.removeNS = function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#normal")).removeClass("active");
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#strong")).removeClass("active");
}
$scope.removeWS = function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#weak")).removeClass("active");
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#strong")).removeClass("active");
}
$scope.removeWN = function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#weak")).removeClass("active");
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#normal")).removeClass("active");
}
```

Further to optimize, you can just create a single function and pass the query selectors and class to remove as the function parameter, like:

```
function(id1,id2,removeClassName)
```